# How To Parse the HTML webpage in Iphone OS 4.0

Tags: iphone, xcode

Hello all I am working On Iphone Os 4.0 ,in that I have some html webpages which changes dynamically .
So could any one explain the way how the html file parsing in Iphone os 4.0
 Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little hard to understand but you might find this library useful: http://github.com/topfunky/hpple

Comment: Hai Andy Thanks for you response. What my need is I need to parse HTML file in xcode project that is running On Iphone os 4.0.